# PySerial client unable to write data

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyserial

I'm trying to write a python program which can communicate over a serial interface using PySerial module as follows:

```
import serial
if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = "/dev/tnt0"
    ser = serial.Serial(port, 38400)
    print ser.name
    print ser.isOpen()
    x = ser.write('hello')
    ser.close()
    print "Done!"
```

But if I execute the above I get the following error:

```
/dev/tnt0
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/root/nested/test.py", line 15, in <module>
x = ser.write('hello')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 518, in write
raise SerialException('write failed: %s' % (v,))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: write failed: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I referred to the pyserial documentation and according to that this should work without an issue. Please let me know what i'm doing wrong in this.
TIA!

Comment: What happens if you execute this in your terminal: `echo "test" > /dev/tnt0`?

Comment: it gives me the same error! `bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument` i'm using a `tty0tty` serial port inorder to emulate a serial port as my machine does not have a serial port...

Comment: Obviously, `/dev/tnt0` is not a serial device. FYI, serial devices *usually* have names `/dev/ttyX` or `/dev/ttySX`, but not necessary.

Comment: Is there a way I can emulate a serial port on a machine just like a device? even if it just acts as an echo server and prints whatever the client is sending to it on the screen... that should be sufficient to test my program...

Comment: Not sure why *tty0tty* does not work, but you could try *socat*: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualSerialPort Also, please accept my answer as it answers your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`/dev/tntX` are emulated port pairs, and to perform a successful read or write you need to open both ports from a pair.

Think of it as a pipe - if one end is closed, you will be not able to push the data through.

Comment: tnt0 through tnt7 are [tty0tty](https://github.com/freemed/tty0tty) emulated ports .. and they work fine with each consecutive port pairs acting as null modem connected.

Answer (score 7):

For some reason, in order to use the module `tty0tty`, you need to open both `/dev/tnt0` and `/dev/tnt1`, or any of the other pairs (e.g `/dev/tnt2` and `/dev/tnt3`).

The code below works:

```
import time
import serial

def main():
     vserial0 = serial.Serial(port='/dev/tnt0', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, stopbits=1)
     vserial1 = serial.Serial(port='/dev/tnt1', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, stopbits=1)

     n_bytes = 0 

     while n_bytes == 0:
          vserial0.write('test')
          n_bytes = vserial1.inWaiting()
          time.sleep(0.05)

     print vserial1.read(n_bytes)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Comment: Thank you for saving me several hours of troubleshooting.  Opening the receiving end with minicom immediately solves the issue.  Note that tty0tty works until you try to write.  That is, the port is recognizable and openable, but the write will always fail unless the receiving port is opened.  Thanks again.